# Gmap3 Not showing maker. Error: latlngliteral

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YHpVX/38/

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

I'm assuming this means that my "lat" and "lng" values are not numeric but instead strings...(correct me if I'm wrong), but how do i fix this? I did a parseFloat.

```
$('#gmap-4').gmap3({
       map:{
           options:{
               center:[29.4401784,-98.4793855],
               zoom:11,
           }
       }
    });

$(document).on('click','table tbody td', function() {
   var lat = parseFloat($(this).parent('tr').attr('data-lat'));
   var lng = parseFloat($(this).parent('tr').attr('data-lng'));
   var latlng = [lat,lng];
   alert(latlng);
   showMarker(latlng);
});


function showMarker(val) {
    $('#gmap-4').gmap3({
        marker:{
            latLng:val
        },
       map:{
           options:{
               center:[29.4401784,-98.4793855],
               zoom:11,
           }
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering...I finally got it:

```
$('#gmap-4').gmap3({
       map:{
           options:{
               center:[29.4401784,-98.4793855],
               zoom:11,
           }
       }
    });

$(document).on('click','table tbody td', function() {
    var lat = parseFloat($(this).parent('tr').attr('data-lat'));
    var lng = parseFloat($(this).parent('tr').attr('data-lng'));
    //alert(latlng);
    showMarker(lat,lng);
});


function showMarker(lat,lng) {
    $('#gmap-4').gmap3({
        marker:{
            latLng: [lat,lng]
        },
       map:{
           options:{
               center:[29.4401784,-98.4793855],
               zoom:17,
           }
       }
    });
}
```